# Angular Translate - How to handle phrases with links

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

The two issues that I have are how to handle this are:

1. I am not sure if it is a good idea to let the translator have control of the actual link / action
2. The issue or rendering translated HTML. [its being rendered as text...]

Is there a best practice / examples on how to handle translations of phrases that need to have links within them?
Would this change if I would like to run some action of the scope when some parts of the text are clicked?

e.g. "BY clicking OK you are accepting our Terms of service and Privacy Policy."

or

"BY clicking OK you are accepting our Terms of service and ."

Comment: The translate *directive* handles links fine. What is your code?

Comment: I am currently just using: `<P>{{ 'KEY_OF_STRING' | translate}}<P>` and it shows the <a href....> from the string assigned to 'KEY_OF_STRING'.

Comment: That's the translate *filter*. Use the translate *directive*.

Comment: Thanks. that solved my issue. I was not aware that the filter and the directive behaved differently. Is there any reference talking about the differences between the two? please post an answer and I will accept.

Comment: I'm stucked with the same issue. Using the directive doesn't seem to work with my version: 2.8.1