# AngularJS Translate : How to handle form text with link?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I use Angular Translate to translate my webapp. I can translate some label, phrase but when i want to translate a phrase which contains a link. The text raw is displayed. 
I want to display a check box :

My json file :

```
 "cgu":"Accept <a href=\"#/ourconditions\"> our Terms and conditions</a>"
```

My check box in form :

```
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="">
        <label for="cgu">
                <input type="checkbox" id="cgu" ng-model="cgu" checked>
                {{"global.form.cgu" | translate}}
                <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="global.form.cgu | translate"></div>
            </label>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Here is what is displayed: the raw text and not the link : 
[image]

I've tried the solution :
[stackoverflow post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26479927/angular-translate-how-to-handle-phrases-with-links)

and [this one](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular-translate/gwTw-Rjmp60)
Nothing is working.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell angular translate to compile the translated string (s. "[Post compiling](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/05_using-translate-directive#using-translate-directive_post-compiling)" at the angular translate homepage).

```
<span translate="{{ global.form.cgu }}" translate-compile></span>
```